# rake still aborts on RuntimeError even though exception is rescued

Tags: ruby, exception, rake

I am working on a rake system, and I have some new code which needs to do some consistency checking.  I would like the code to not exit on the first error; I would like it to continue to finish checks on the rest of the data.  If it does hit a consistency error, it can throw an exception.  I am trying to use a simple construct just to catch RuntimeError:

```
 begin
      <code which may throw RuntimeError...>
 rescue RuntimeError => e
      <print info about exception ...>
 end
```

This seems to execute the rescue block; the error message from the rescue is printed.  The problem is that rake still aborts, even though the exception has been caught and handled.  Is there some setting in rake which sets abort_on_exception to true?  Is there any way yo change this?  I do not want it to abort on this exception, I just want the error printed, and to continue with the rest of the checks.  It will exit on a higher level if the complete consistency check reported an error.  Perhaps I need to throw something other than a RuntimeError?  I am just using raise with a string argument.

Comment: `RuntimeError` is raised when an exception occurs that isn't otherwise categorized. What happens if you replace `rescue RuntimeError => e` with `rescue => e`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try Exception insted of RuntimeError exception

```
begin
  <code which may throw RuntimeError...>
rescue Exception => e
  p e.message
  p e.backtrace
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I have been working on the code quite a bit so I don't know if I have the exact same circumstances I was hitting yesterday.  With the "rescue Exception" I found that it caught the first error but was throwing another "undefined method `some_method' for nil:NilClass" exception later.

Comment: So now you will get the exact error, and you can fix that, as early as possible. :) :)